# Conversion from type 'JObject' to type 'String' is not valid

Tags: vb.net

I am running into an issue in VB.net where a remote system returns me a list of Json Objects in form of System.Collections.Generic.List. I can loop thru the list and get each row which is a JsonObject which looks somewhat like this

```
{
  "Demo": {
    "_id": "8ebf5297-64bb-4c92-9883-0b528e3af26c",
    "_type": "cname",
    "status": "pending",
    "batch": 0,
    "action": null,
    "number": "2135551212",
    "cname_text": "DEMO CENAME",
    "history": {
      "created_on": "2019-11-08T12:41:56.1182915-08:00",
      "created_by": "DEMO",
      "batch_date": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
    }
  }
}
```

so how can i convert this into a regular object so i can easily access the values ?
I tried

```
Dim myData = JObject.Parse(row)
```

and

```
Dim myData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))(row)
```

Both create the error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred
>   in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll Conversion from type 'JObject' to type
>   'String' is not valid.

Comment: Perhaps this article on this forum might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416497/parse-nested-json-with-json-net-in-visual-basic

Comment: Not really as it does not address what causes the error

Comment: You need to actually create an object that reflects the json structure and deserialize to that

Comment: You access with data with: something = myData("Demo")("_id").tostring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After driving me nuts i figured it out. The remote service returns data which VB.net does not see as a string but a JObject which cant be converted to a string. So to get around this i created a structure and then used the JObject from to Object method to get my Json object into a normal object.

```
Dim tmpRow = JObject.FromObject(row).ToObject(Of CnameRecord)
```

Answer (score 0):

The easier way is:

```
Dim jResults As JObject = JObject.Parse(value.ToString)
```